# Selenium Firefox Webdriver sometimes not closing

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

my problem is that sometimes when I am  testing a website, the FF webdriver is not closing the Browser Window after the test, although it continues the testing process until there are so many windows open that there is no memory left.
I have tried using driver.close() and driver.quit(), as well as both of them, but SOMETIMES they just do not seem to work. Is there a way to force the driver to quit? I looked into killing the process but I can't seem to get the PIDs of the started Webdrivers...
Am I the only one who has encountered this problem yet?

Comment: If there is no `@Aftermethod` or `@AfterClass` annotations in your program, you can use try/catch/finally blocks and put your driver.quit() or driver.close() in the finally method.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I am not sure how your code looks like (since you didn't provide it) but usuall flow for this kind of test is to have class with following methods.

```
public class TestClass {

     private WebDriver driver;

     @BeforeClass
     public void setUp() {
         driver = new FirefoxDriver(); //or any other one
     }

     @Test
     public void test1() {}

     @Test
     public void test2() {}

     @AfterClass
     public void tearDown() {
         driver.quit();
     }
}
```

Note that you don't have to call `WebDriver#close` or `WebDriver#quit` in the test methods, you can just reuse the browser session during testing.

Comment: not sure I agree with this though.. the `@Before` and `@After` methods should be called per-method. not before and after the class like this is.

Comment: I guess it depends on the testing scenario, I am usually trying to test one page with one class so this approach makes sense. Anyway, good point!

Comment: When you use `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass` the methods has to be static and accordingly the instance variable, too.

Comment: You are right - this is how it works in JUnit. However in TestNG methods don't have to be static.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `driver.quit()` in the framework tearDown for **each testCase**, just as you should assign it in the framework setUp for each testCase.
Have a look here http://siking.wordpress.com/2013/02/28/what-is-wrong-with-groovytestcase-and-selenium/ which somewhat describes your problem.

Answer (score -1):

I got Firefox to work with driver.quit(). What I did was uninstall my current version and downloaded an older version of Firefox from this directory that Modzilla keeps public:
https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/

The version I downloaded was “Firefox Setup 27.0.exe” from here:
https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/27.0/win32/en-US/

Everything worked after that.

---

Before I switched Firefox versions, I used Firefox browser to download Selenium IDE from here:
http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/
 [image]

Selenium IDE is a Firefox Plugin.

What I think was happening was this= When I had Firefox version 32 (newest version) and I looked in the “Extensions” options, the Selenium IDE wouldn’t show up. Now that I have Firefox version 27, the Selenium IDE shows up and it looks like this: 
[image]